# Quickblox 1:2 or multi user chat same time

Tags: android, quickblox

Hi All I am developing an chat app using Quickblox api for android. And 1:1 chat is working fine but my issue is how can i get a notification that some other user also message me during the chat like in other chat app. I check there api but not find anything regarding background notification. There is example for push notification but push is not fit with chat. So can anyone know how to handle this issue or any example to handle it using quickblox. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your are offline then QuickBlox will deliver to you offline push notification when someone sends a message

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Push_notifications_to_the_offline_users

You have to enable it in Dashboard

Comment: Thanks Igor, I will check this.